# Having trouble sending images/files to API using reactjs and Material UI upload component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui, multer

I created an image upload component using an upload component from Material UI. I have done this in the past using just an html file input so I am getting confused. The files get selected just fine and put them into the component state. When I append them to form data and send to server(node & expressjs) I keep getting an empty array from req.files. I am using multer on the server-side for parsing files.

Here is the UI component:

```
const StepFive = ({
  handlePrevStep,
  setListingImages,
  listingImages,
  createdListing,
}) => {
  const created = useSelector((state) => state.listings.created);
  const [fileList, setFileList] = React.useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setListingImages(fileList);
    console.log(fileList);
  }, [fileList]);

  const onChange = ({ fileList: newFileList }) => {
    setFileList(newFileList);
  };

  const handleLisitingImages = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData();

    //check if image(s) have been selected yet
    //and append the images to form data
    if (fileList) {
      for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        data.append('listingImage', fileList[i]);
      }
    }

    console.log(data.getAll('listingImage'));

    uploadImagesToListing(createdListing._id, data)(dispatch);
  };

  const onPreview = async (file) => {
    let src = file.url;
    if (!src) {
      src = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      });
    }
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    const imgWindow = window.open(src);
    imgWindow.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  };

  // const prevStep = (e) => {
  //   e.preventDefault();
  //   handlePrevStep();
  // };

  // if (!created) return <Spinner />;

  return (
    <Con>
      <Wrap>
        <Header>
          Step <b>5|5</b>
        </Header>
        <SubHeader>Pictures</SubHeader>
        <SubInfo>
          This is the most important part of creating a listing and attratcing
          guests. Really spend time on taking some good quality pictures of your
          place
        </SubInfo>
        <UploadForm enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <ImgCrop rotate>
            <Upload
              listType='picture-card'
              fileList={fileList}
              onChange={onChange}
              onPreview={onPreview}
              name='image'
            >
              {fileList.length < 15 && '+ Upload'}
            </Upload>
          </ImgCrop>
        </UploadForm>
        <BtnCon>
          <Btn onClick={prevStep}>Prev</Btn>
          <Btn onClick={handleLisitingImages}>Finish</Btn>
        </BtnCon>
      </Wrap>
    </Con>
  );
};
```

here is the uploadImagesToListing function:

```
export const uploadImagesToListing = (listingId, images) => async (dispatch) => {
  await axiosInstance
    .post(`/listings/imageupload/${listingId}`, images, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;` },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: uploadedImages,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

now on the server here is the route with multer:

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();

//allows routes to get files
const multipleUpload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('listingImage');

router.post(
  '/imageupload/:listingId',
  verifyToken,
  multipleUpload,
  listings.imageUpload
);
```

In the route handler all I do is try to console.log(req.files) and keep getting an empty array.

****SOLVED****
When accessing each file object from the inputs, I need to add fileList[i].originalfileObject instead of just fileList[i]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the axios like

```
export const uploadImagesToListing = (listingId, images) => async (   dispatch ) => {   await axiosInstance
    .post(`/listings/imageupload/${listingId}`, images)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: uploadedImages,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }); };
```

Comment: Please apply this issue, if problem not solved please comment here @stinny